# PHP cURL to upload video to azure blob storage

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage

I have issues to create a new/simple PHP script/function with cURL to upload simple file (video.mp4) from local server to Azure storage - blob container using authentication key. I do not want (for other reasons) use SDK and/or multiple files/libraries. I need only one function - fileUpload - and that is it.

I am able to get the key using another function without any issue but when I try to upload the file using the below fileUpload function I am facing the following error

`InvalidHeaderValue`The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:798508a1-701e-0055-0e82-efab9f000000
Time:2023-09-25T07:34:50.5926245ZContent-Length-1

```
function uploadFileToAzureBlob($key, $container, $azureUrl, $uploadedFile, $fileArray){

    $url = $azureUrl.$container."/".pathinfo($uploadedFile["file"], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    echo json_encode($uploadedFile)."<br>";
    echo json_encode($fileArray)."<br>";
    echo filesize($uploadedFile["file"])."<br>";

    $ch = curl_init();
    echo $url."<br>";

    // Open file
    $fileHandle = fopen($uploadedFile["file"], 'r');
    // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Set the HTTP method to PUT
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');

    // Set the body of the request to the contents of the file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fileHandle);

    
    $headers = array(
        "Transfer-Encoding" => "chunked"
        ,"x-ms-blob-type" => "BlockBlob"
        ,'x-ms-version'=>'2017-11-09'
        , "x-ms-date" => gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', time())
        ,"Content-Type" => $fileArray["type"]
        ,"Content-Length" => filesize($uploadedFile["file"])
        ,"Authorization"=>$key);

    echo json_encode($headers)."<br>";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_map(function($v,$k){
                                                        return $k.":".$v;
                                                    },$headers,array_keys($headers)));
                                                echo $fileArray["size"]."<br>";
    // Set the size of the file for the Content-Length header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileArray["size"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    // Execute the CURL session
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo json_encode($response)."<br>";
    echo "curl:::: " .json_encode(curl_getinfo($ch))."<br>";
    // Close file and CURL session
    fclose($fileHandle);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Could you please help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Content-Length-1` - not sure if that is a quirk from the system generating the error message, or if that actually means the value you sent for the `Content-Length` header was just `1`. Have you _checked_ what header values you are actually sending there?

Comment: Hi @lakshyya Kothari have you tried with SAS-token to upload?

Comment: @CBroe , I have checked the header values being sent and the value for `Content-Length` is not -1 it's around 46000 (which is the size of the file being uploaded). I tried the same with Postman too. But faced the same error. Not sure what am I missing here.  I feel like i'm missing something really small.

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan, I do not want to use that method. We are already performing the same operation of generating  the token by hitting an api and then using the generated token as the authorization header for our current call. This functionality is working in springboot but now I have to do the same using php

Comment: Not sure if `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is actually true here ...? I don't think a normal cURL file upload request is sent in chunks?

Comment: `return $k.":".$v;` in your array_map call there will result in `HEADERNAME:HEADERVALUE` pairs - not technically incorrect, whitespace between the colon and the value is not _required_ - but it is rather convention to include a space after the colon anyway, and I would suggest to always do that, to avoid problems with receiving systems that might not follow the specification exactly.

Comment: @CBroe, before adding `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` I was getting HTTP status 411. Saying that the request needs to be chunked and the content-length needs to be specified even though I was specifying the `Content-Length`. After I passed the `Transfer-Encoding` header the error changed to `InvalidHeaderValue`

Comment: In authorization headers, you can't pass directly the access key see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key

Comment: I think you might need to provide your own `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` for a chunked upload? https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/issues/369

Comment: That's weird because we are doing the same thing in our spring boot project and we are passing the key via the headers. Please note that we are generating the key via an oauth2 api call to azure blob storage

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, I'll try that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PHP cURL to upload the video to Azure blob storage

To upload video from local to Azure blob storage using **`Put blob`** request you can use the below PHP code.

I used a 5MB sample video file to upload Azure blob storage.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$storageAccountname = 'youraccount name';
$accesskey = "youraccount key";
$filepath = realpath('./test.mp4');
$containerName = 'your-container-name';
$blobName = 'demo.mp4';

$URL = "https://$storageAccountname.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";

function uploadBlob($filepath, $storageAccountname, $containerName, $blobName, $URL, $accesskey) {

    $Date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
    $handle = fopen($filepath, "r");
    $fileLen = filesize($filepath);

    $headerResource = "x-ms-blob-cache-control:max-age=3600\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12";
    $urlResource = "/$storageAccountname/$containerName/$blobName";

    $arraysign = array();
    $arraysign[] = 'PUT';               /*HTTP Verb*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Encoding*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Language*/  
    $arraysign[] = $fileLen;            /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-MD5*/  
    $arraysign[] = 'video/mp4';   /*Content-Type*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Date*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Modified-Since */  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Match*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-None-Match*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Range*/  
    $arraysign[] = $headerResource;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
    $arraysign[] = $urlResource;        /*CanonicalizedResource*/

    $str2sign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

    $sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($str2sign)), base64_decode($accesskey), true));  
    $authHeader = "SharedKey $storageAccountname:$sig";

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: ' . $authHeader,
        'x-ms-blob-cache-control: max-age=3600',
        'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-date: ' . $Date,
        'x-ms-version: 2019-12-12',
        'Content-Type: video/mp4',
        'Content-Length: ' . $fileLen
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileLen); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo ('Uploaded successfully<br/>');
    print_r($result);

    curl_close($ch);
}

uploadBlob($filepath, $storageAccountname, $containerName, $blobName, $URL, $accesskey);
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Put Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=shared-key#request)

Comment: This is working fine for me too! Thanks :) I was under the impression that the ops team wouldn't provide me with the access key but they did. So it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Although the weird part still is that why is something which is working in springboot not working here.. a question for another day tho.