# Generating SAS token for Azure Blob storage in PHP with REST API

Tags: php, azure, rest, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have a PHP (Laravel) + React.js (with Intertia) app that I'm building that needs to use Azure Blob Storage for image uploading and serving images. I've successfully built an uploader on the frontend that relies on a SAS token. My intent was to use the Valet Key pattern to generate this SAS token from the PHP backend, and serve it to the frontend when the page is rendered (I'm using Socialite on the PHP / Laravel side for authentication with Entra ID).

Now the PHP storage client libraries are being retired, and we're forced to use the raw REST API, I'm really struggling to generate the SAS key on the server side for my valet key pattern. I haven't been able to find a single example online of someone else who's successfully integrated the REST API.

Really struggling here and could do with some guidance and / or an example.

Thanks,

Luca

Comment: Please take a look at the source code for Account Shared Access Signature: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-common/src/Common/SharedAccessSignatureHelper.php or Blob Shared Access Signature: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-php/blob/master/src/Blob/BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper.php. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

> Generate a SAS token for Azure Blob storage in PHP with the REST API.

In my environment, I first cloned the repository using the command below:

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-php.git
```

Next, I installed all dependencies using `composer install` and created a PHP file named **`example.php`** in the root directory.

**Code:**

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Autoload dependencies
require_once 'src/Blob/BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper.php';

use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper;

// Replace these values with your Azure Storage account details
$accountName = 'xxxx';
$accountKey = 'xxxxx';
$containerName = 'block-image';
$blobName = 'bike.png';

// Create BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper instance
$blobSasHelper = new BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper($accountName, $accountKey);

// Generate a shared access signature for the blob
$signedResource = 'b'; // Blob resource type
$resourceName = $containerName . '/' . $blobName;
$signedPermissions = 'r'; // Read permission
$signedExpiry = new DateTime('2024-02-01T00:00:00Z');

$sasToken = $blobSasHelper->generateBlobServiceSharedAccessSignatureToken(
    $signedResource,
    $resourceName,
    $signedPermissions,
    $signedExpiry,
);

// Construct the full URI with the generated SAS token
$blobUriWithSas = "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName?$sasToken";

// Output the generated SAS token and the URI with the SAS token
echo "Generated SAS Token: $sasToken\n";
echo "Blob URI with SAS token: $blobUriWithSas\n";
```

**Output:**

To get the generated SAS token, run the above code using **`php example.php`**.

```
PS xxxxphpsasproject\azure-storage-blob-php> php example.php
Generated SAS Token: sv=2017-11-09&sr=b&se=2024-02-01T00:00:00Z&sp=r&sig=xxxxx
Blob URI with SAS token: https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/block-image/bike.png?sv=2017-11-09&sr=b&se=2024-02-01T00:00:00Z&sp=r&sig=xxxxx
```

[image]

After copying the Blob SAS URL and pasting it into the browser for recheck purposes, the image was displayed successfully.

**Browser:**
[image]

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, this library is being retired. im trying to find a more sustainable solution than using a deprecated library.

Comment: As of know there is no new library.

Comment: Yep which is why I wanted to use the REST HTTP API with CURL. I managed to make it work in the end, but having issues with block blob storage PUTs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792702/subject-azure-blob-storage-issue-with-mac-signature-mismatch-in-block-blob-up

Comment: I will check now

Comment: @NaveenSharma Hey mate, unfortunately this solution didn't solve the problem according to the question, I did specifically specify "Now the PHP storage client libraries are being retired, and we're forced to use the raw REST API" and the answer then goes on to suggest using the deprecated API...

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77170696/php-curl-to-upload-video-to-azure-blob-storage/77171664#77171664 Check whether it helps.

Comment: that deffo helps solve my initial question (this one), but for uploading larger files I should be using block blob uploads no? The answer you linked there doesnt seem to upload in blocks

Comment: What is your file size need to upload?

Comment: upto around 5gb

Comment: I think you tried with Javascript I saw in your other answer.