# Subject: Azure Blob Storage - Issue with MAC Signature Mismatch in Block Blob Upload

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-blob-storage, blob

I'm currently facing an issue with uploading block blobs to Azure Blob Storage using the REST API. I'm constructing the string-to-sign as per the Azure documentation, but I'm consistently receiving a 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. error.

```php
$str2sign = "PUT\n\n\n$blockSize\n\n$blockMimeType\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12\n$headerResource\n$urlResource";
```

Where `$headerResource` is `x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12` and `$urlResource` is `/$storageAccountname/$containerName/$blobName\nblockid:" . urlencode($blockId) . "\ncomp:block"`.

I'm then creating the signature as follows:

```php
<?php
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($str2sign)), base64_decode($accesskey), true));
?>
```

And the authorization header:

```php
<?php
$authHeader = "SharedKey $storageAccountname:$sig";
?>
```

The headers for the request are set as follows:

```php
<?php
$headers = [
  'Authorization: ' . $authHeader,
  'x-ms-date: ' . $Date,
  'x-ms-version: 2019-12-12',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($blockList),
  'Content-Type: application/xml',
];
?>
```

And the request is sent using curl:

```php
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $blockList);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Despite following the documentation, I'm still facing this issue. I've also ensured that the `Content-Length` header is included in the string-to-sign if it is included in the request, and that the query parameters in the CanonicalizedResource part of the string-to-sign are in lexicographical order.

Interestingly, I have other functions for uploading and showing blobs that are working fine, which are using the same method for authentication. Here's an excerpt from the `show` function:

```php
<?php
// Azure Blob Storage download
$Date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');

$headerResource = "x-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12";
$urlResource = "/$storageAccountname/$containerName/$blobName";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'GET';               /*HTTP Verb*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Encoding*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Language*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-MD5*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Type*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Date*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Modified-Since */
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Match*/
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-None-Match*/
?>
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please try by changing `$arraysign[] = 'GET';` to `$arraysign[] = 'PUT';`. Also populate content length value in the array as well.

Comment: the 'GET' is from my example from my (working) show function, which retrieves a blob. in the str2sign at the top of the question you can see im using PUT. Please re-read the question carefully. @GauravMantri

Comment: Could you please include a block list?

Comment: This issue is occurring whether I upload 1 or multiple blocks, it's still an Authorization issue. The block list seems irrelevant no? @Venkatesan

Comment: Are you trying to upload block (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block?tabs=microsoft-entra-id)? Please ensure that the headers in the request and `$headerResource` match the specification in REST API.

Comment: I ended up restructuring my app to use a vallet key pattern with a SAS key, and handling the blob storage on the frontend using the javascript azure blob storage npm package.

Comment: Please post as an answer so it will be helpful to other community.

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.